# C++ test if lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, sfinae

I'm making a hooking library, which basically intercepts a function and makes it jump to the intercept function.

```
class CHook
{
public:

    template<typename S, typename D>
    void SetupHook(S Source, D Destionation)
    {
        pSource = (PBYTE)Source;
        pDestination = (PBYTE)Destionation;
    }

private:
    PBYTE pSource;
    PBYTE pDestination;
};
```

I want CHook::SetupHook to take (for Destination) either DWORD (address of function), function pointer which both can be type casted to PBYTE.

I want CHook::SetupHook to also be able to take a function pointer from lambda but it cannot be type casted to PBYTE so I overload it and since I know lambda function are classes I use std::is_class to identify them.

```
template<typename S, typename D>
void SetupHook(S Source, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<D>::value, D>::type Destionation)
{
    pSource = (PBYTE)Source;
    pDestination = (PBYTE)Destionation;
}

template<typename S, typename D>
void SetupHook(S Source, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<D>::value, D>::type Destionation)
{
    pSource = (PBYTE)Source;
    pDestination = (PBYTE)to_function_pointer(Destionation);
}
```

But it results in these erorrs:

```
error C2783: 'void CHook::SetupHook(S,std::enable_if<std::is_class<D>::value,D>::type)': could not deduce template argument for 'D'
note: see declaration of 'CHook::SetupHook'
```

Comment: Try `template<typename S, typename D>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<D>::value>::type SetupHook(S Source, D  Destionation)` instead (ditto the second overload)

Comment: that works, post it as the answer and ill select it as the answer. Also, any explanation for this?

Comment: If you're storing a pointer in it (assuming you're doing this on Windows) PVOID might be a better choice than DWORD. A DWORD is defined to be a 32-bit unsigned integer, which isn't going to do well when storing a pointer on a 64-bit system. Or avoid the platform-specific types altogether if you're tying to make it portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write code like:

```
template <typename S, typename D>
void SetupHook(S Source, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<D>::value, D>::type Destionation)
{
    // (...)
}
```

you make `D` a non-deducible type template parameter. That is, a type template parameter list, `<typename S, typename D>`, does **not** correspond to the parameter list of a function, and so, the compiler can't tell which type template parameter it is supposed to deduce in place of

```
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<D>::value, D>::type
```

Formally, a nested name specifier introduces a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/3953764).

The solution is let the compiler deduce `D`, as a plain parameter type, and to put `std::enable_if` elsewhere, e.g.:

```
template <typename S, typename D>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_class<D>::value>::type SetupHook(S Source, D Destionation)
{
    // (...)
}
```

Now, the compiler sees that `D` is the type of the second argument expression.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hack-y trick, but you can convert a lambda to a function pointer using unary+.  Note that you can't convert a lambda to a function pointer if it captures any variables.

```
template<typename S, typename D>
void SetupHook(S Source, D Destionation)
{
    pSource = (PBYTE)Source;
    // static_cast is required for avoiding Visual Studio bug
    pDestination = (PBYTE)+static_cast<void(*)()>(Destionation);
}
```

...

```
void some_func() {}

int main() {
  auto str = "hello";
  auto some_lambda = [](){};
  auto some_capturing_lambda = [=]() {
    std::cout << str;
  };
  SetupHook(str, some_func);               // Works
  SetupHook(str, some_lambda);             // Works
  SetupHook(str, some_capturing_lambda);   // Error in Unary Expression
}
```

Comment: I wouldn’t call this a hack. The only real use of unary `+` is to invoke conversions.

Comment: I had no idea about this, so simple! I was using a long method to get the function pointer, thanks!

Comment: I also need to be able to pass raw function address e.g. 0x401000 into the parameter source/destination, will unary + not work with that? I think I will still need a seperate overload for raw function address and have like a std::is_integral check, something like that

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get these errors: `>Main.cpp(38): error C2593: 'operator +' is ambiguous
1>  Main.cpp(38): note: could be 'built-in C++ operator+(void (__cdecl *)(void))'
1>  Main.cpp(38): note: or       'built-in C++ operator+(void (__stdcall *)(void))'
1>  Main.cpp(38): note: or       'built-in C++ operator+(void (__fastcall *)(void))'
1>  Main.cpp(38): note: or       'built-in C++ operator+(void (__vectorcall *)(void))'`

Comment: @Budskii what are you passing for that case?  Looks like you're using visual studio, what version?  I tested this on clang and gcc.

Comment: I basically copy and pasted your code, errors for both lambda arguments passed to SetupHook() and yes, I am indeed using visual studio

Comment: @Budskii Apparently this is a bug in Visual Studio.  Workaround is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26220743/1843316  I will update my answer